# Call a piece fo CAS login webflow

Tags: spring-webflow, cas

I have a CAS 3.4.9 using the login webflow.
I need to call directly the login webflow at a particular action/view.
How can it be done?

If it is not possible (I believe a security reason), How can have on CAS another "service" using another webflow?
And in this manner, what is the link I must use to call it?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options. Extending the class in which you want to make the call, for instance at generateServiceTicket, or create a new class and inject your class into the CAS login webflow.

I have injected a trap in my CAS login webflow to check to see if a user has accepted a policy in the last 365 days.

Normally in the `warn` decision state, it will return the redirect action state, but instead I am trapping the user so the policy will be checked.

```
    <decision-state id="warn">
            <if test="flowScope.warnCookieValue" then="showWarningView" else="checkPolicy" />
    </decision-state>
```

It then transitions into my `checkPolicy` state

```
    <action-state id="checkPolicy">
        <evaluate expression="checkPolicyAction"/>
            <transition on="success" to="redirect"/>
            <transition on="error" to="viewLoginForm"/>
            <transition on="redirectPolicy" to="redirectPolicy"/>
            <transition on="gateway" to="redirectPolicy"/>
    </action-state>
```

The expression `checkPolicyAction` is defined in the cas-servlet.xml to the java class which executes the `doExecute` method and returns back to the webflow various states as you see in the previous xml. Just to top it off, `redirectPolicy` redirects the user to a new service that will then have them accept the policy and they can then continue on to what they intended to do.

Take a look at https://github.com/Unicon/cas-password-manager - This is where a company has extended the login-webflow of CAS to trap for password updates. This is where I got most of my ideas on how to trap the user. Also the CAS User Manual https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CASUM/ is a great resource.